# How to show hidden divs on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseover

How to show a set of hidden div's onmouseover?

For example :

```
<div id="div1">Div 1 Content</div>
<div id="div2">Div 2 Content</div>
<div id="div3">Div 3 Content</div>
```

All div's need to be shown onmouseover event.

Comment: Please provide more detail.  On mouseover of what?

Comment: What do you mean by hidden divs?  Do you mean visibility is set to "hidden" or display is set to "none"?

Comment: Question needs improvement, clarification, more detail.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If the divs are hidden, they will never trigger the `mouseover` event.

You will have to listen to the event of some other unhidden element.

You can consider wrapping your hidden divs into container divs that remain visible, and then act on the `mouseover` event of these containers.

```html
<div style="width: 80px; height: 20px; background-color: red;" 
        onmouseover="document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';">
   <div id="div1" style="display: none;">Text</div>
</div>
```

You could also listen for the `mouseout` event if you want the div to disappear when the mouse leaves the container div:

```
onmouseout="document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';"
```

Answer (score 19):

There is a really simple way to do this in a CSS only way.

Apply an opacity to 0, therefore making it invisible, but it will still react to JavaScript events and CSS selectors.
In the hover selector, make it visible by changing the opacity value.

```css
#mouse_over {
  opacity: 0;
}

#mouse_over:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div style='border: 5px solid black; width: 120px; font-family: sans-serif'>
<div style='height: 20px; width: 120px; background-color: cyan;' id='mouse_over'>Now you see me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow that's a great tip thank you!  that's just what I wanted, making it invisible but triggering the events

Answer (score 13):

You could wrap the hidden div in another div that will toggle the visibility with onMouseOver and onMouseOut event handlers in JavaScript:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #div1, #div2, #div3 {  
    visibility: hidden;  
  }
</style>
<script>
  function show(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible";
  }
  function hide(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
</script>

<div onMouseOver="show('div1')" onMouseOut="hide('div1')">
  <div id="div1">Div 1 Content</div>
</div>
<div onMouseOver="show('div2')" onMouseOut="hide('div2')">
  <div id="div2">Div 2 Content</div>
</div>
<div onMouseOver="show('div3')" onMouseOut="hide('div3')">
  <div id="div3">Div 3 Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass the mouse over the container and go hovering on the divs I use this for jQuery DropDown menus mainly:

Copy the whole document and create a .html file you'll be able to figure out on your own from that!

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>The Divs Case</title>
            <style type="text/css">
            * {margin:0px auto;
            padding:0px;}

            .container {width:800px;
            height:600px;
            background:#FFC;
            border:solid #F3F3F3 1px;}

            .div01 {float:right;
            background:#000;
            height:200px;
            width:200px;
            display:none;}

            .div02 {float:right;
            background:#FF0;
            height:150px;
            width:150px;
            display:none;}

            .div03 {float:right;
            background:#FFF;
            height:100px;
            width:100px;
            display:none;}

            div.container:hover div.div01 {display:block;}
            div.container div.div01:hover div.div02  {display:block;}
            div.container div.div01 div.div02:hover div.div03 {display:block;}

            </style>
            </head>
            <body>

            <div class="container">
              <div class="div01">
                <div class="div02">
                    <div class="div03">
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1** Each div is specifically identified, so any other div (without the specific IDs) on the page will not obey the :hover pseudo-class.

```
<style type="text/css">
  #div1, #div2, #div3{  
    display:none;  
  }  
  #div1:hover, #div2:hover, #div3:hover{  
    display:block;  
  }
</style>
```

**Option 2** All divs on the page, regardless of IDs, have the hover effect.

```
<style type="text/css">
  div{  
    display:none;  
  }  
  div:hover{  
    display:block;  
  }
</style>
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it is not possible to hover over a div that is not displayed.

Comment: Yes, the opposite would be possible, but not like this.

Comment: Then I would use the visibility:hidden/visible rule instead. Good point.

Comment: Unfortunately I believe visibility:hidden has the same problem on hover, despite the div not collapsing like with display:none.

Comment: You should be able to use this css approach with a container div, assuming the container is visible: 
eg div#container:hover div#child {display:block;}

Answer (score 0):

```
<div
  style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #666;"
  onmouseover="this.style.display = 'none';"
>
Hello World
</div>
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.