# Render text on hover rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to implement a feature i have been seen around lately. When a mouse hovers on a div/image some text is rendered on it. How can this be achieved using rails ? also what exactly is this feature called ? Just like [this site.](http://www.builtinlondon.co/)

Comment: Have you examined the page you linked to to see how it works? I'd guess that it is just an absolutely positioned `<div>` on top of the image that is bound to a hover.

Comment: It's a roll-over, created easily using JavaScript. This isn't a Rails thing, though Rails could serve a page containing that JavaScript.

Comment: @Joshua I've removed the `ruby` and `ruby-on-rails` tags; this question has nothing to do with either of those technologies.

Answer (score 0):

The thing about web programming is that you need to know html, css, javascript, *and* a server side language like ruby (ruby-on-rails).  You don't create *rollovers* with rails.  You create *rollovers* with either css or javascript.

css: http://accessibility.psu.edu/rollovers
js: [How to show hidden divs on mouseover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707100/how-to-show-hidden-divs-on-mouseover)

css and javascript are both things that can go in a web page.

jQuery is a library that can make programming javascript easier.