# Display hidden css classes

Tags: css

How to display hidden css classes on hover

```
<a class="a1">Show the first</a>
<a class="a2">Show the second</a>

<div class="div1">The first</div>
<div class="div2">The second</div>
```

I think it's clear

thanks!

Comment: Sorry but no, it's not clear. What is supposed to be hidden? What will be hovered? And where are the classes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show hidden divs on mouseover?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707100/how-to-show-hidden-divs-on-mouseover)

Comment: @Ryan, not really: this one specifies *only* [tag:css], not [tag:javascript].

Comment: @bfavaretto I have added the clesses

Comment: If you can move the divs between the `<a>`s, Mite Mitrski's answer should work.

Answer (score 2):

A CSS only option would be to have 2 classes and with one you hide the `div` element as with the others you display it using the pseudo selector `:hover`

```
div {
    display: none;
}

a:hover + div {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I believe you managed to understand the question. You should just mention that this solution requires the html to be changed, it should be a + div, then a + div (not a + a then div + div).

Comment: @bfavaretto I don't want to change the html

Comment: @Mite Mitresk It works only if I changed the html but i don't want to

Comment: @Ahmed Added an answer, there's a similar selector that does the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors):

```
div { display: none; }
.a1:hover ~ .div1 { display: block; }
.a2:hover ~ .div2 { display: block; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uK8KP/

Comment: thanks, what about IE is there a way with javascript?

Comment: This is supposed to work on IE7+, according to MDN.

Comment: My mistake I tried it in IE10 with a local page -that's why it hasn't worked-

Comment: @bfavaretto this looks more complete to me