# Trying to make button appear onmouseover

Tags: javascript, visibilitychange

I am trying to make it so that when i mouse over where this button is, it appears.

here is my code

html:

```
<div class="hide"><button type="button" onmouseover="appear()" id="button">LIGHT!!</button></div>
```

css:

```
div.appear {display: none;}
```

javascript:

```
function appear(){document.getElementById("button").style.display = "block";}
```

Comment: well if the button is hidden, there is no way to fire an event

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show hidden divs on mouseover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707100/how-to-show-hidden-divs-on-mouseover)

TLDR: if the element is hidden, you cannot bind events to that element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hidden element has no mouse events so you would need to use opacity.

```css
.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.hide:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="hide"><button type="button" id="button">LIGHT!!</button></div>
```

You can hide it if you apply the hover/mouseover to the parent

```css
.hide {
  height: 30px; 
  width: 200px;
}

.hide > button {
  display: none;
}

.hide:hover > button {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="hide"><button type="button" id="button">LIGHT!!</button></div>
```